# How to run a non main queue in a background state?

Tags: ios, objective-c, grand-central-dispatch

Please take a look at this very simple piece of code:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
   
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
    {
        NSLog(@"LOOP %d", i);
        sleep(1);
    }
});
```

If I send my app to the background state it is still running. Yet if I put the execution onto a non main queue like this:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0), ^{
    
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
    {
        NSLog(@"LOOP %d", i);
        sleep(1);
    }
});
```

then the execution is suspended when my app is going to the background. Is it possible to make it run in a background state when dispatched on a non main queue?

I need to mention that I'm running my app with these background modes enabled:

```
<key>UIBackgroundModes</key>
<array>
    <string>bluetooth-central</string>
    <string>voip</string>
</array>
```

Comment: It's not possible to make things on the *any* queue (including the main queue) run indefinitely in the background. The first block of code will cause your app eventually to be force-killed rather than just suspended due to blocking the main thread. If you're not seeing that, you're probably running under Xcode (which loosens some of the rules). iOS has many tools for running in the background, but no general-purpose tool. Which tool you use depends on exactly what problem you're solving. None of them solve "run whatever I want in the background."

Comment: I forgot to mention that I've got some background modes enabled. I've updated my question. please take a look

Comment: If you want a few seconds (max of 30) to finish something after the user leaves the app, see [`beginbackgroundtaskwithname:expirationHandler:`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiapplication/1623051-beginbackgroundtaskwithname/), but that buys you only 30 seconds. You can’t just keep running in background in perpetuity. For more info, see [Choosing Background Strategies for Your App](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/backgroundtasks/choosing_background_strategies_for_your_app).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In addition to using `performExpiringActivityWithReason`, you can use the `UIBackgroundTaskIdentifier` API:

```
// Perform the task on a background queue.
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0), ^{
   // Request the task assertion and save the ID.
   self.backgroundTaskID = [[UIApplication sharedApplication]
              beginBackgroundTaskWithName: @"Finish Pending Tasks" expirationHandler:^{
       // End the task if time expires.
       [[UIApplication sharedApplication] endBackgroundTask:self.backgroundTaskID];
       self.backgroundTaskID = UIBackgroundTaskInvalid;
   }];
        
   // Add your code here.
        
   // End the task assertion.
   [[UIApplication sharedApplication] endBackgroundTask:self.backgroundTaskID];
   self.backgroundTaskID = UIBackgroundTaskInvalid;
};
```

The expiration handler is what gets called before the app is killed, but don’t plan on doing computationally expensive tasks using this method since the OS has system-wide time limits which are out of the developer’s control.

If you need to perform specific tasks in the background for certain system events like network fetches, then consider using a Background Mode.

[image: bg modes ios]

The advantage of using the UIKit API, in this case, is you can query `[[UIApplication sharedApplication] backgroundTimeRemaining]` within your for loop to perform any last-minute cleanup steps.

Note that if you’re using App Extensions Apple recommend using the `NSProcess` API, so advice will vary depending on the use case.

Comment: I forgot to mention that I've got some background modes enabled. I've updated my question. please take a look

Comment: bg modes only allow you to add logic on delegate callbacks, see [bluetooth-central callbacks](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corebluetooth/cbcentralmanagerdelegate) for more info. Similarly for voip.

Comment: ok. thank you, buddy. this seems to be working well. I need to refresh my knowledge of the background modes. I thought they allow any sort of a background execution

Answer (score 1):

Please try using `NSProcessInfo performExpiringActivityWithReason` API

```
[[NSProcessInfo processInfo] performExpiringActivityWithReason:@"myReason" usingBlock:^(BOOL expired)
{
  // This block is run on a separate (background) thread
  // Put your code here...
}
```

please note this is only a request for some additional CPU time on a process that is being backgrounded ... you cannot run background code indefinitely.

The block will be invoked a 2nd time with `expired == YES` when you're about to be killed.